# Gradient color disappears after showing full screen

Tags: highcharts

My project is about using gradient color in Highcharts, but when the user views in Fullscreen then escape/exit, the gradient effect disappear after 1 or 2 times trying.

I have checked on Highcharts and it has the same bug, please help to clarify, thanks.

Step to reproduce:

- Choose Edit in JsFiddle
- In menu list, choose Full screen
- Escape

This is a demo from highcharts :

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-gradient

Comment: That's probably a bug in Highcharts. You can open a bug report here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues